# Laravel 5: sort products by categories,

Tags: php, laravel, model, scope, eloquent

I dont have a lot of experience with laravel but i am trying to sort my products on categories... 
I can already sort all products but not by categorie.

Could you guys help me out?

Model:

```
class Product extends Model {


protected $table = 'products';


public function getCategoriesListAttribute(){
    return $this->categories()->lists('id');
}


public function categories(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Modules\Webshop\Models\ProductCategory', 'category_product', 'product_id', 'category_id')->withTimestamps();
}}
```

Products table:

```
    Schema::create('products', function(Blueprint $table)
    Schema::create('category_product', function(Blueprint $table)
    Schema::create('product_categories', function(Blueprint $table)
    Schema::create('product_tag', function(Blueprint $table)
```

Controller:

```
class ProductsController extends Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        //$this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $viewmodel = array(
            "categories"=> ProductCategory::where('visible', '1')->get(),
            "products" => Product::has('categories')->get(),
            "page"=>Page::where('href','=', '/')->first(),
        );
        return view('Webshop::frontend.view.products.index', $viewmodel);
    }

}
```

The index() shows only the products who have any category.

If you guys need more information feel free to ask :)

EDIT:

I am trying this in my controller.

```
 public function index()
{
    $viewmodel = array(
        "products" => Product::with('categories')->where('category_id','23'),
    );
    return view('Webshop::frontend.view.products.index', $viewmodel);
}
```

and this:

```
  $viewmodel = array(
        "products" => Product::leftJoin('category_product', 'category_product.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
                        ->leftJoin('product_categories', 'product_categories.id', '=', 'category_product.category_id')
                        ->where('category_id', 23)
                        ->first(['products.*']),
    );
    return view('Webshop::frontend.view.products.index', $viewmodel);
```

I have a category with id 23.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Yes I have spend so many hours trying to find out how to show products of a category.. I have added the controller to my question. I am just stuck at the index() function in my controller. Here it shows all products who has any category. So that is not specific.

Comment: What do you mean 'sort by category' you are selecting products with a specific category_id how can you sort on only one category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it!

I added this to my model

```
 public function scopeGetCategorieSlug($query, $category_slug)
{
    return $query->leftJoin('category_product', 'category_product.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
                ->leftJoin('product_categories', 'product_categories.id', '=', 'category_product.category_id')
                ->where('product_categories.slug', $category_slug)
                ->get(['products.*']);
}
```

and this to my controller

```
public function show($category_slug)
{
    $viewmodel = array(
        "categories"=> ProductCategory::where('visible', '1')->get(),
        "products" => Product::getCategorieSlug($category_slug),
        "page"=>Page::where('href','=', '/')->first(),
    );
    return view('Webshop::frontend.view.products.index', $viewmodel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you really mean 'sort', use `orderBy()` query builder method. If you need to order by some data, located in another table, use `join()` to include those fields into your query. Pay attention, that when using `join()` in Eloquent Builder, you need to also use `select("products.*")` or Laravel will try to fetch incorrect columns into your query result.

If you need to group query result by categories, use `group()` method of the query result's collection. You can group by `category_id` field.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Now I am doing a left join but it gives back the following error: Trying to get property of non-object. What am i doing wrong? You can see the code in my updated post.